# Cannot change state from url bar with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, frontend

When I try to go directly to an url like mysite.com/#!/about I always get redirected to the home state. I have a menu with ui-sref links which are working fine. It's working fine with ngRoute but I have nested states so I cannot switch... As you can see I'm not doing anything special... You can check the complete source here: https://github.com/misterch0c/SL-frontend

```
.config(function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $popoverProvider, envServiceProvider, ngDialogProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: 'home',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            },
            'filters@home': {
                templateUrl: 'views/filters.html',
                controller: 'FiltersCtrl'
            },
        }
    })

    .state('about', {
        url: 'about',
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    });

angular.extend($popoverProvider.defaults, {
    placement: "bottom",
});

})

.run(['$state',
  function($state) {
  $state.transitionTo('home');
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define your url *(of each state)* with leading slash '/'

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        ...
```

Comment: Wow... That was it. Thanks A LOT! I've been on this for several days... I feel stupid bu so released at the same time